# What will be the type of a value that is hash in state in its api file in corda?

Tags: corda

What will be the type of a value that is hash in state in its js file in corda? I have defined a variable in state as secure hash:
val x: SecureHash

What will be the type of variable in api file? Is the following correct?
@QueryParam("x") x: SecureHash

(for party type, in api we used to put like CordaX500Name,like that for SecureHash it is needed or not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like below
`@QueryParam("x") val x: SecureHash`

Corda has provided de-serialize for `SecureHash` type. If it's not working then you could use String type to bind query parameter, then parse the string in your method like 
`SecureHash.parse(stringValue)`